# Go to another activity in Android Studio after last question in a quiz

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

I am a beginner in android studio.I am making a quiz app where the quiz crashes after the last question.I want to switch activity after the last question.Please Help.This is how I tried.But the code is not working.

```
btnnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mQuestionNumber==5){
                Intent i = new Intent(QuizOne.this, ResultOne.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }else {
                updateQuestion();
```

Comment: Post the logcat of the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little bit of Android Development. It looks like your intent is never made unless the question number is equal to 5. Try :

```
btnnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener) {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ResultOne.class);

        if (questionNumber == 5) {
            myIntent.putExtra("answer", someValue);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
```

To receive that info in the other activity, set a variable equal to the intent's contents:

```
String answer = getIntent().getStringExtra("answer", someValue);
int value = getIntnet().getIntExtra("answer", someValue);
```

By specifying the contents of the intent, you can now which activity was used to go to the current one.

Also make sure the ResultOne activity is specified in the Android Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".ResultOne"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

check if your ResultOne Activity is registered in the manifest and how your ResultOne activity is supposed to process the answers if you didn't passed any data to your intent.

```
i.putExtra("some key",someValue);
```

it propebly crashes in the second activity